# Vectorize numpy array expansion

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to find a way to vectorize an operation where I take 1 numpy array and expand each element into 4 new points.  I'm currently doing it with Python loop.  First let me explain the algorithm.

```
input_array = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

I want to 'expand' or 'extend' each element in this array to 4 points.  So, element zero (value 1) would be expanded to these 4 points:

```
[0, 1, 1, 0]
```

This would happen for each element to end up with a final array of:

```
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0]
```

I'd like to make the code slightly generic so that I could also perform this 'expansion' in a different way.  For example:

```
input_array = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

This time each point is expanded by adding += .2 to each point.  So, the final array would be:

```
[.8, .8, 1.2, 1.2, 1.8, 1.8, 2.2, 2.2, 2.8, 2.8, 3.2, 3.2, 3.8, 3.8, 4.2, 4.2]
```

The code I'm currently using looks like this. It's a pretty naive approach that works but seems like there would be a way to speed it up for large arrays:

```
output = []
for x in input_array:
    output.append(expandPoint(x))

output = numpy.concatenate(output)

def expandPoint(x):
    return numpy.array([0, x, x, 0])

def expandPointAlternativeStyle(x):
    return numpy.array([x - .2, x - .2, x + .2, x + .2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to want to do elementwise operations between `input_array` and the array that contains the extending elements. For these, you can use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

For the first example, it seems you are performing `elementwise multiplication` -

```
In [424]: input_array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
     ...: extend_array = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0])
     ...: 

In [425]: (input_array[:,None] * extend_array).ravel()
Out[425]: array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0])
```

For the second example, it seems you are performing `elementwise addition` -

```
In [422]: input_array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
     ...: extend_array = np.array([-0.2, -0.2, 0.2, 0.2])
     ...: 

In [423]: (input_array[:,None] + extend_array).ravel()
Out[423]: 
array([ 0.8,  0.8,  1.2,  1.2,  1.8,  1.8,  2.2,  2.2,  2.8,  2.8,  3.2,
        3.2,  3.8,  3.8,  4.2,  4.2])
```

Comment: Ah, I never thought about using multiplication and addition. Seems obvious now that I see it.  Thanks!

Comment: This approach and the `ufunc` approach with `outer` seem equivalent but I'll go with this one since it was first.  I've tested both and they seem the same in terms of performance.

Answer (score 2):

For the first example, you can use `np.kron`

```
>>> a = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0])
>>> np.kron(input_array, a)
array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0])
```

For the second example, you can use `np.repeat` and `np.tile`

```
>>> b = np.array([-0.2, -0.2, 0.2, 0.2])
>>> np.repeat(input_array, b.size) + np.tile(b, input_array.size)
array([ 0.8,  0.8,  1.2,  1.2,  1.8,  1.8,  2.2,  2.2,  2.8,  2.8,  3.2,
        3.2,  3.8,  3.8,  4.2,  4.2])
```

Comment: This is good to know!  However, it won't work in my scenario because the input numbers are all over the place. They aren't 'regular' like 1, 2, 3, 4.  I just used that as an example.

Comment: What do you mean by "all over the place"?

Comment: I mean not predictable, bad choice of words on my part.  I looked into `iron` because I'd never seen it before and it seems like it will work.  I previously thought your solution was tied to the numbers being 0 and 1, I was wrong.

Comment: This solution might not be the best, but I think it is one possible idea.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain of the logic of your algorithm, but I think if you want each point to `extend` around it, and then queue them all together, your best approach would be to increase the dimension, and then take the flattened version; for your first example:

```
>>> x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> x
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> y = np.empty((len(x), 4))
>>> y[:, [0, 3]] = 0
>>> y[:, 1:3] = x[:, None]
>>> y
array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  2.,  2.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  3.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  4.,  4.,  0.]])
>>> y.reshape((4*len(x),))  # Flatten it back
array([ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  0.,  0.,  3.,  3.,  0.,  0.,
    4.,  4.,  0.])
```

How you then go about making that generic depends on your algorithm, which I'm not entirely sure to follow... But this should give you some pointers to get started.

*Edit*: As others have stated, you can actually do all that with outer products in a much more concise way, which will probably match your algorithm more closely, e.g., shamelessely making YXD answer a one-liner:

```
>>> (x[:, None] * np.array([0,1,1,0])[None, :]).flatten()
array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0])
```

However, the principle is still to go in a higher dimension (2) before expanding it in you original dimension (1)

Answer (score 1):

For the first example, you can do an outer product of the input and the template and reshape the result:

```
input_array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
template = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0])

np.multiply.outer(input_array, template)
# array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
#        [0, 2, 2, 0],
#        [0, 3, 3, 0],
#        [0, 4, 4, 0]])

result = np.multiply.outer(input_array, template).ravel()
# array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0])
```

Similarly for your second example you can use `np.add.outer`

```
np.add.outer(input_array, [-0.2, -0.2, 0.2, 0.2]).ravel()
# array([ 0.8,  0.8,  1.2,  1.2,  1.8,  1.8,  2.2,  2.2,  2.8,  2.8,  3.2,
        3.2,  3.8,  3.8,  4.2,  4.2])
```

See:

- http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.  This looks ike it will work and seems the most straight-forward so far.

Comment: For this example looks like using the calls to outer are direct equivalents to the broadcasting approach below from @divakar. I wonder if there's a convention for using one over the other?

Comment: Yes they are equivalent `np.multiply` and `np.add` are "ufuncs" which can take care of broadcasting for you - see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html